# How to maintain Chrome "enable request blocking" after closing dev tools?

Tags: windows, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

I am talking about the feature in Chrome, opening the 3-dot-menu at the top right of the dev tools > More tools > Request blocking

This feature is amazing, and it remembers the domains/urls to block, however every time you close the dev tools it un-checks the box "Enable request blocking".

I want to block some stuff all the time, regardless of whether the dev tools are open... Is there a way to keep this from un-checking itself?  It is possible to keep it open in the background, but it doesn't even transfer to a new tab if the current tab opens a new one.  Perhaps there are some new flags that can be set in newer versions (now we are on Chrome 79, and this question was originally asked with Chrome 63).

[image]

Comment: Try using https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/domain-blocker/ggdcjplapccgoinblmidpkoocfafajfa.

Comment: of all extensions, domain-blocker actually worked

Answer (score 3):

Opened up a chrome ticket to add this. If you think this would be a useful feature, then voting there will help get it on the radar. https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1269320

Comment: It is pretty much an ad blocker so I wouldn't get my hopes up!

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately not the solution. However my workaround for that is to have the dev-tools as a separated window either minimised or just in the background if i don't need or want them.